# Missing "left screen" in my SGS1 . How can it be added?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, home-screen

I have stuff on the 7th screen and I've expected to be able to reach it on left swipe from homescreen, but it is not so. 
How can I configure it ? Does it require some non-default launcher?

Comment: Can you navigate the screens in circular fashion (right swiping on the last screen takes you back to first screen). If this is not the case then you can't go directly to 7th screen by left swiping on first screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an option in most launchers, but I think it's not available in the stock launcher. I'd recommend switching to Launcher Pro, there it's enabled by default and can be toggled from `Preferences -> Homescreen settings -> Homescreen looping`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the original Samsung supplied OS with  Samsung's Touchwiz interface, then it doesn't wrap around, to get to the 7th screen you have to scroll seven screens to the right.

Alternatively you can "pinch" zoom out on any of the home screens to zoom out and see an overview of all of your screens, and tap any of them to move straight to them. You can also add and remove screens (up to 7) from here, by dragging unwanted screens to the trash bin at the bottom of the screen, or clicking the plus sign to add another (up to 7).

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your homescreen, there should be a row of white dots, one for each screen. You can tap them to skip directly to selected homescreen.